# Shifting a vector in a 3D matrix

Tags: matrix, octave, shift

Given *m* a 3D numerical matrix, how to circular-shift the elements contained in the vector `m(1,1,:)`?  (I mean shift "and store" in the same matrix.)

When prompted for this vector, Octave will return

```
octave> m(1,1,:)
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =  *value*
...
ans(:,:,n) =  *value*
```

which is not precisely a vector, in the sense that are `m(:,1,1)` and `m(1,:,1)`. Actually, first question would be: how to extract such a vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `squeeze(m(1,1,:))` to convert it to a 1-D vector. In general when you perform `m(1,1,:)`, it returns a Tensor of size `N*1*1`. `squeeze` does the work you want. After process the vector, you can do modification simply by assigning `m(1,1,:)=ModifiedVector`. Hope this helps.